# How fast does getting last known location in android work?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

In my android app, I want to get the last known location. I am following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html.

Basically when the activity loads, I display info which is manipulated based on the current location, so I need the location first. I want to know how long it can take for it to get the location or fail trying. Should I attempt to wait and get the location then display the content, or cache the location and then use it so I don't have to wait. ( I prefer no cache)

I don't want the user to wait long, a few seconds is ok i guess.

Also in the 3 callback methods `onConnectionSuspended`, `onConnected` and `onConnectionFailed`, can I be sure that 1 of these will be called no matter what the situation is, (like no internet, no gps, or some random error somewhere)?

Comment: Have you actually tried this yet?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `getLastLocation()` will return immediately.

The connection to Google Play Services may take some time to succeed or fail, you can never be sure. You might want to show a Dialog to the user while you are waiting for the connection.

You will definitely call a callback on either `onConnected()` or `onConnectionFailed()`. You can rely on that.

Comment: How fast getLastLocation changes ? I know it depends on other apps

Comment: There is no definite time. If the GPS on your device hasn't been used for a while, it can take a long time before first fix. It has to warm up, find the satellites, calibrate, etc. If you are in an are of bad reception, it can also take a very long time. And different devices have different hardware. Some is good, some not so good. If you have Internet connection, this can help speed up the process. It is also possible to get an approximate location using cell ID and nearby WIFI devices, but this is all very variable. There isn't really a definite answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. I tested getLastLocation() in a car while the google map was on. getLastLocation was changing quite rapidly. But when I closed the map, getLastLocation was not changing at all.

Comment: If you are only calling `getLastLocation()`, but you never request any location updates yourself, then you will only get updated location if another app requests location updates. Calling getLastLocation does not trigger a location update.

Comment: Yep. That is correct. Google Maps calls for location updates which is why calling getLastLocation() gets an updated location when Google Map is running in background.